# Cross browser acceptance for 'display:normal ' css

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am using a CSS class as:

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}

.show{
    display:normal
}
```

If we want to consider all cases flex, block and inline in a app with single css class like we have display:none. Since some elements may be flex, block,inline-block etc. What should be that single css i.e. opposite of display:none and consider element wise.

The css `display:normal` is working fine in chrome, mozilla firefox but less aware of its cross browser affect and disadvantages.

Comment: `normal`is not a valid value for display: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: But, its working fine in chrome.

Comment: When you say "it works fine", what does it do?

Comment: It is displaying the content.

Comment: it's not working fine, the browser is simply ignoring it and using the default value because it's **invalid**

Comment: Then you want to use block or inline-block or whatever the elements display was before you set it to none.  Chrome may handle erroneous code better and default to something like block if a display value is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

There is no *normal* value for `display`. However, the two most common values are `display: inline` and `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no normal value for display property, You Can use display:block; display:inline; and display:inherit; for this..

Comment: i would use `display:initial` if it is not a flex or grid direct child, else block or inline will matter.

Comment: @G-Cyr, what if we want to consider all cases flex,block and inline in a app with single css class like we have display:none. Since some elements may be flex, block,inline-block etc. What should be the universal css ie opposite of display:none and consider element wise.

Comment: @Mahi via CSS you should not have to mind the display reset, it will turn back to the original class. In javascript, add remove a class to trigger display:none; no need to mind about resetting display, it follow the style like it was. If you want to reset display via js fter display:none, reset it to null . `element.style.display="";`  css and javascript : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GVoYpz but the good practice is to toggle (add/remove) a class not reset style on the fly. The answer is actually, you do not need the class show, you  need to remove the class hide to show anything you hide.